# Why smooth vector field, not non smooth ones?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

I'm following L Tu's book. I am confused by the notion of smoothness. I have two questions, (1) Why does smoothness captured by infinitly differentable, if we have k times differentiable function, does that mean it is less smooth than the k+10 differentiable function? But in what way is less smooth?
(2) Why do we need a smooth vector field, what if it is not smooth vector field, what smoothness can do for us in the notion of vector field.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: if you apply a vector field $X$ to a smooth function $f$,  it is really convenient to get again a smooth function $Xf$; if either $X$ or $f$ is not $C^\infty$, then $X^mf$ may not exist for large $m$'s

Comment: The interpretation of the tangent space of a manifold at $p$ as the space of derivations at $p$ acting on (germs of) smooth functions depends crucially on the $C^\infty$ notion of smoothness. If you do $C^1$ functions, for example, the space of derivations all of a sudden becomes infinite-dimensional. I believe you can find this discussed in various posts on this site.

Comment: From a practical point of view, vector fields with some finite degree of smoothness are important, but most results for them can be derived from the smooth case by density arguments. The smoothness just simplifies things. Roughly, if a theorem holds for smooth vector fields, and the theorem still makes sense for rougher vector fields, then it is usually true for rougher vector fields.

Comment: "Smooth" was just a convenient term to use to describe levels of differentiability. It does not indicate anything other than that the function is differentiable a number of times, and if that number is finite, the result is still continuous. Most commonly "smooth" indicates $C^\infty$, but sometimes authors will define it to mean some lower degree of smoothness, almost always $C^1$ or $C^2$. This will depend on their needs for whatever subject they are covering. One other thing: referring to just "L. Tu's book" is only helpful if "L. Tu" has written only one book.